# Highcharts - toggle table properly upon drilldown item

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

In my Web application I am displaying some tabular data upon drilldown of a bar chart, and upon drillup the related table should be disappeared.

If you may, please check the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/yvhsg8r9/), upon clicking the items individually the toggle is working fine, but when I drilldown multiple bar charts at once, not all of them are acting as expected.

```
{           
        drilldown: function(e) {
            this.update({
              xAxis: {
                plotBands: [{
                  color: '#FFF',
                  from: -0.5,
                  to: e.seriesOptions.data.length,
                  label: {
                    text: e.point.name,
                    align: 'center'
                  }
                }],
              }
            }, true);
            if( e.point.name == 'Started - F15' ){
                minMaxData_15Fa.toggle();
            }
        },

        drillup: function() {
            this.update({
                xAxis: {
                    plotBands: [{
                    from: 0,
                    to: 0,
                    }],
                }
            }, true);

            if(tableToggle == 'F15'){
                minMaxData_15Fa.toggle();
            }
        }
```

The fiddle is only a reproducible example, my application would contain about 6 to 8 of those bar charts, can anyone take a look and correct me where I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't noticed you are using a single variable that stores the status of table toggle, this might work in a scenario where only one source of drilldown exists, but you have multiple drilldown instances, and hence the problem.

Check this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kumar4215/s75hL914/), a simple solution I can come up would be to maintain the status of a particular table toggle in unique variable, and you should be good.

```
var tableToggle15Sp;
var tableToggle15Fa;
```

Let me know in case of any concerns. Appreciate any feedback.